# Do I accrue progress towards the next KPI milestone if I don't collect its perk points?

Tags: deep-rock-galactic

In my pod bay of the space rig is the screen with Key Performance Indicators (KPIs) with milestones that, when completed, award perk points. When a milestone is marked as completed, I've always immedaitely collected the points. If I don't immediately collect the points, do I still accrue progress towards the next milestone? Must I clear the completed milestone first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the progress is still tracked fully without collecting the perk points.

It can even happen that after a while of not checking the KPI milestones that you can collect the same milestone multiple times.